# React Native: Problem with the modules of my application?

Tags: android, react-native, compiler-errors

I just put together a project in react native and when compiling it with the command "gradlew assembleRelease" on android I get this message:

I am trying to compile [this project](https://github.com/imandyie/react-native-airbnb-clone).

[`Error image when compiling`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WMXu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just running on android gives clearer error massages.
1. $yarn install
2. $react-native run-android

I get a bundle error for Node.

> bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `AccessibilityInfo`
>   from
>   `D:\Android\Project\react-native-airbnb-clone-master\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\react-native\react-native-implementation.js`:
>   Module `AccessibilityInfo` does not exist in the Haste module map

I might has something to do with your RN Version. They introduced a lot of Accessibility features in 0.57, so it might help to updated RN.
See: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading